# How to authenticate to active directory using trusted domain user?

Tags: java, active-directory

Using Active Directory Domains and Trusts, I added the trusted domain named domainB.com for the domainA.com
Using this code to authenticate to active directory, I get the error "LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, vece"

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://domainA.com:389/");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "domainB\\userB");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "*******");
env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
InitialLdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null); //this line will cause error
```

How can I authenticate to AD using the trusted domain user?
Thank you for your help

Comment: userB@domainB.com should do the trick, if that is the user's userPrincipalName attribute value.

Comment: this problem might not be a java problem at all, but rather a configuration problem of the Active Directory Domain. You should read Microsofts Doku on authentication via a trusted Domain. Maybe you'll find some clue there.

Comment: With domainB\userB, I can use ADSIEdit to get the connection settings for domainA.com, so I don't think that it is a configuration problem.

Answer (score 0):

error 49 usually means bad credentials.

Also in the last line you can use

```
DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

JNDI will do the rest.